# Citrix has issues resolving network shares

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, citrix, share

We are having this weird issue with our Citrix (version 4.5) server (sitting on Windows 2003 r2), where a couple users have issues resolving single shared network drive.  We use a logon script to map all shared drives.  The weird part is that of 3 shared drives, users can access 2, but the 3rd one goes to the old server (even though the logon script points to the new server).  And that issues is limited to a few users.  I had them log off and re-loggin to no success.  It happens just in Citrix.

The file server, that is being accessed, is Windows 2008 R2.  Like I said we use a logon script to map the network drive.  I understand I might be a little confusing, I will gladly reword the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to have each of the affected users delete all of their shares (net use /d *) and then log out and back in. Your login script may not be mapping drives that were already mapped to the old server.

Also, add some logging/debugging statements to your login scripts - if you don't know what's going on, we can only guess based on what you tell us.

Comment: @George Agreed, this can be added to your logon script. if this still fail check local name resolution and dfs namespace links if you use them.

Comment: @mfinni Silly me, that's Network 101, I simply removed the mapped drive and had user re-login.  That did the trick!  Thank you!